# How to use local files in a bootstrap video carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a website for my assignment and I want a carousel of videos. So I found a template for bootstrap carousel and the video linked to some server played. I would like to know how I can get local videos to play as well. I tried changing the source to my local video file, but it is not working. Can someone please tell me how I can play my videos on a bootstrap carousel. Don't worry about big size div.

```
  <div class="bigsize">
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--Slides-->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <video  autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Tropical.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your local files should be located on same dir (or below) as your HTML file to show them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your local file in the Video carousel then you need to specify the exact location of that file from the current directory.

For Example:
Your file is located inside assest>>Videos>>file.mp4 from the current working directory of .html file. The code for that would like something this--

```
<video  autoplay loop muted>   
<source src="\assest\Videos\file.mp3">
</video>
```

I Think this might help you what you are looking for if you have any furhur issue that you can ping me.

Comment: Hey. How can I get it to play the audio. When I take the audio tag out, the file doesn't play.